# How to install a NativeScript plugin from a forked repository?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I currently need to use the nativescript-https plugin but its repository is not updated and not packed to npm and it has a couple bugs [(including one with AFNetworking with version)](https://github.com/gethuman/nativescript-https/issues/36)  without a solution so I've forked the repository and try to add from this forked repo using:

`tns pluging add [url of the repo]`

this install the plugin with no errors, but when I try to run the app it shows the following error:

> NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not find module 'nativescript-https'

So I would like to know... which is the correct workflow to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error wasn't related to the plugin installation, the problem was that I needed to run Typescript compiler on plugin's folder to generate the .js files.

Answer (score 1):

Compile and add the plugin folder to your `package.json` using relative path.

```
"myplugin": "file:myplugin/dist"
```

Assuming `myplugin` is your plugin folder placed at your project root, `dist` is where you have your compiled JS files.

Comment: Hi Manoj, can you explain how to compile a repo?

Comment: Follow the plugin guide, generally you will find compile scripts in `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run the pack command and get the tgz file.